# laravel whereNotIn not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two different laravel query and i want to use second query with `whereNotIn` based on first query. but `whereNotIn` seems not working because the data still shown.

this the first query

```
$detailservice = DetailServiceOrder::leftJoin('services', 'detail_service_orders.service_id', '=', 'services.id')
    ->select('detail_service_orders.*',
       'services.service_name')
    ->where('sales_order_id', $id)
    ->get();
```

this the second query

```
foreach ($detailservice as $data) {            
        $service[] = Service::whereNotIn('id', [$data->service_id])->get();    
    }

    dd($service);
```

and here my `dd($service)` result sample

```
#attributes: array:4 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "service_name" => "Mail Service"
      "created_at" => "2016-11-26 02:15:24"
      "updated_at" => "2016-11-26 02:15:24"
    ]
 #attributes: array:4 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "service_name" => "Network Maintenance"
      "created_at" => "2016-11-15 07:00:45"
      "updated_at" => "2016-11-15 07:00:45"
    ]
```

and here my `dd($detailservice)` result sample

```
#attributes: array:10 [▼
    "sales_order_id" => 6
    "service_id" => 1
    "order_type" => "add"
    "select_plan" => "test 1"
    "qty" => 2
    "unit_price" => 200.0
    "note" => "testing 1"
    "updated_at" => "2016-12-22 01:34:00"
    "created_at" => "2016-12-22 01:34:00"
    "service_name" => "Network Maintenance"
  ]
#attributes: array:10 [▼
    "sales_order_id" => 6
    "service_id" => 2
    "order_type" => "change"
    "select_plan" => "test 2"
    "qty" => 3
    "unit_price" => 400.0
    "note" => "testing 2"
    "updated_at" => "2016-12-22 01:34:00"
    "created_at" => "2016-12-22 01:34:00"
    "service_name" => "Mail Service"
  ]
```

the above `dd($service)` result should not shown because it was filtered on second query.

Comment: What does `dd($detailservice);` show?

Comment: hi, i was edited my question add the `dd($detailservice)`

Comment: Thanks. Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. First, it gets results where ID is not 1 (so, it gets 2) and then it returns results where ID is not 2 (returns object where ID is 1).

If you want to get results where ID is not 1 or 2, use this instead of `foreach()`:

```
$services = Service::whereNotIn('id', $data->pluck('service_id'))->get();
```

Comment: Hi, it's working, but I'm get another trouble. Now the result was not show the ID 1 or ID 2, because when I'm `dd($data->pluck('service_id'));` the result is `#items: array:12 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => 1
    3 => 1
    4 => 1
    5 => 1
    6 => 2
    7 => 2
    8 => 2
    9 => 2
    10 => 2
    11 => 2
  ]`

Comment: I didn't understand the question from your comment, could you rephrase it please.

Comment: Currently, it's not show the service, because when I debug the `$data->pluck('service_id')` it's shown the `service_id` value is `1` and `2` (like my comment above). which mean, it's will not filter the ID 1 or ID 2, but the ID 1 and ID 2, so the all data was not shown. CMIIW